# what happens to open pull request on a merged branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-merge

I have a branch A from master. I created another branch on branch A, let's say branch AA and made few changes on AA.

I then created a pull request of the changes on AA and pointed it to branch A.

Due to some reason, I had to merge branch A back into the master branch.

Now I have an open pull request of AA pointing to A and github shows the Merge Pull Request button to be green (implying that I can safely merge).

Is it fine if I merge the changes I made on AA to branch A? Or should I close the pull request and create a new pull request pointing to the master, since branch A has already been merged into the master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it fine if I merge the changes I made on AA to branch A?

No problem, you could merge. But it's surely not what you want to do in the end...

To we'll understand what it will do, you should try to visualise the history (perhaps on a paper sheet!).

If you merge AA into A, you will have a new merge commit in A but this commit won't be merge inside master because created after the merge of A in master. If you want that the commits in AA finish also in master, you will be obliged to merge again A in master.

> Or should I close the pull request and create a new pull request pointing to the master, since branch A has already been merged into the master?

It's better if you want a simpler history but the 2 solutions will end in the same result...